# TSQL - row values to column headings including further column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

my input is a View with the following columns:

```
DOCID   DATE    ROWNUMBER   COLUMN1     COLUMN2     COLUMN3     COLUMN4     COLUMN5
ABC000123   2014-04-11  1   approval    project name    ABC     (null)      (null)
```

The records of **COLUMN2** need to become **column headings** with ***either*** a value of COLUMN3 or COLUMN4. If COLUMN3 is empty or null then use COLUMN4.
At the moment COLUMN5 is completely empty so you can ignore this column.

The thing is that not every **DocID** contains all the values in **COLUMN2** that are needed to build the headings.

So I thought using something like "`SELECT DISTINCT column2 AS headings`" over all entries of the View and then using the pivot function could get me somewhere.
But I couldn't get it to work.

I also need to be able to select only certain column heading regarding COLUMN2. Maybe this is easier once I have a view with all columns to choose from and create a new view from that.

Have a look at this **sample**
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df226/1/0)

I use MSSQL 2012.

I'd be happy for some sample code.

Thank you.

Comment: The column headings are fixed and cannot be data dependent, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Can you use the markdown output in sql fiddle to include all of the sql in your question? Also, can you show your desired output (trimmed if required) based on that dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you will need to unpivot the columns `Column3`, `Column4`, and `Column5` first to return the rows that are not null, then pivot the `Column2` items into columns.  If you don't know the column names you'll need to use dynamic SQL inside of a stored procedure.

Before using dynamic sql, I'd first write a static version of the query to get the correct logic. Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use CROSS APPLY and VALUES to unpivot the data:

```
select 
  m.docId,
  m.Date,
  m.column1,
  m.column2,
  c.value
from dbo.mappingTest m
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Column3', Column3),
    ('Column4', Column4),
    ('Column5', convert(varchar(10), Column5, 120))
) c (Col, Value)
where c.value is not null
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df226/9).  Your data now looks like this:

```
|      DOCID |       DATE |  COLUMN1 |      COLUMN2 |   VALUE |
|------------|------------|----------|--------------|---------|
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval | project name |     ABC |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval | article name |  Art 01 |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval |     customer |    ACME |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval |   department | Dept. A |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval |        plant |  Europe |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval |    sop month |      10 |
```

You have multiple rows for each `DocID` with the values you'll eventually want under the `Column2` items in a single column.  Now you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
select 
  DocID,
  Date,
  Column1,
  [project name], [article name], [customer],
  [department], [plant], [sop month],
  [sop year], [eop month], [eop year], [budget], [savings]
from 
(
  select 
    m.docId,
    m.Date,
    m.column1,
    m.column2,
    c.value
  from dbo.mappingTest m
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('Column3', Column3),
      ('Column4', Column4),
      ('Column5', convert(varchar(10), Column5, 120))
  ) c (Col, Value)
  where c.value is not null
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for column2 in ([project name], [article name], [customer],
                  [department], [plant], [sop month],
                  [sop year], [eop month], [eop year], [budget], [savings])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df226/10). I've included all column names, but inside of the PIVOT `IN` you'd include only the values you actually want as the new columns.

Now if you want to use dynamic SQL, you'll adjust the code to be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN2) 
                    from dbo.mappingTest
                    group by COLUMN2
                    order by COLUMN2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'SELECT 
        DocID,
        Date,
        Column1,' + @cols + ' 
      from 
      (
        select 
          m.docId,
          m.Date,
          m.column1,
          m.column2,
          c.value
        from dbo.mappingTest m
        cross apply
        (
          values
            (''Column3'', Column3),
            (''Column4'', Column4),
            (''Column5'', convert(varchar(10), Column5, 120))
        ) c (Col, Value)
        where c.value is not null
      ) d
      pivot 
      (
        min(value)
        for column2 in (' + @cols + ')
      ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df226/2). Both versions will give a result of:

```
|      DOCID |       DATE |  COLUMN1 | ARTICLE NAME | BUDGET | CUSTOMER | DEPARTMENT | EOP MONTH | EOP YEAR |  PLANT | PROJECT NAME | SAVINGS | SOP MONTH | SOP YEAR |
|------------|------------|----------|--------------|--------|----------|------------|-----------|----------|--------|--------------|---------|-----------|----------|
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 | approval |       Art 01 |  17890 |     ACME |    Dept. A |         0 |    21019 | Europe |          ABC |  (null) |        10 |     2014 |
| ABC000123  | 2014-04-11 |  project |       (null) | (null) |   (null) |     (null) |    (null) |   (null) | (null) |       (null) |  -0,020 |    (null) |   (null) |
| DEF000123  | 2014-05-11 | approval |       Art 02 | (null) |   (null) |     (null) |    (null) |   (null) | (null) |          DEF |  (null) |    (null) |   (null) |
```

Comment: fantastic @bluefeet Thank you very much for the code and detailed explanations - this works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you know all the values.  Then you can write a pivot query.  I tend to use conditional aggregation for pivots:

```
create view v_table as 
    select docid, date,
           max(case when column2 = 'project name' then column3 end) as ProjectName,
           . . .
    from table t
    group by docid, date;
```

This is a guess as to the structure of what you want (one row per document and date).

You will have to modify the view as new column names are added.